# How does this node/express route accomplish an update? Or does it?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm looking at this code in a nice book on Web Development with Node and Express, and I can't see how this route would update anything at all.

```
Example 6-13. PUT endpoint for updating
// API that updates a tour and returns JSON; params are passed using querystring

app.put('/api/tour/:id', function(req, res){
    var p = tours.some(function(p){ return p.id == req.params.id });
    if( p ) {
        if( req.query.name ) p.name = req.query.name;
        if( req.query.price ) p.price = req.query.price;
        res.json({success: true});
    } else {
        res.json({error: 'No such tour exists.'});
    }
});
```

It seems to be tacking the updated information onto the boolean `p` which is created on line 5. Shouldn't it be tacking it onto some element in the `tours` array?

Am I missing something or is this some errata that needs to be reported to the publisher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read this if `tours` is an Array, `p` will be a boolean as returned by `Array.prototype.some` and thus this code won't do anything useful. However, if `tours.some` is a custom-defined method that returns the first matching tour instance, then the snippet might make sense, but we need to understand what `tours` is to see the whole picture.

Comment: the example is given with no other context... so I think it's a typo in the book. Thx for the confirmation.